# TI-84 Matrix Fractions Question

Tags: calculator

Apologies if this isn't the place to ask!

I use a TI-84 CE. When I run the RREF for saved matrices, I often get decimals returned in the output. I'm wondering if there's a way to consistently convert them to fractions? Sometimes, they're simple enough to just eyeball, and sometimes I can use the >N<>D function to convert them, but there's been many times it doesn't work, and I end up having to just do the row reduction by hand. This would save me a LOT of time and frustration, and I'd greatly appreciate a work-around :')

Answer (score 0):

MODE > ANSWERS > FRAC > ENTER